# Is Google using the password show/hide toggle icon on their login form correctly?

Tags: forms, password, gmail

[image]

Shouldn’t the icon be the action that ***will*** happen *after* you click/press on it? ...similar to when a video or song is playing, the icon showing is “Pause” (future state), and when it is paused, the “Play” icon is shown.

Comment: ah, whoops, I should have thought to look for duplicates before answering...

Answer (score 1):

Toggles can be a design challenge for this very reason.

Sometimes toggle icons indicate the current state: the common "lock / unlock" (or "enable / disable") icon of a padlock follows this pattern:  if the padlock is open, the item is currently unlocked (and clicking it will close it); if the padlock is closed, the item is currently locked (and clicking it will open it).

In other common cases, such as your play/pause button example, a toggle does the exact opposite, and shows the state that will result from interacting with it, not the current state.

In this particular case, since the icon represents a physical object -- an eye, that is either open or "closed" (crossed out) -- I would expect the toggle to follow the same pattern as the padlock, i.e. show the current state. Which is what they're doing.

But even if they'd gone the other direction I wouldn't feel comfortable saying they're doing it *wrong*.  Because there *isn't* a hard-and-fast rule on this, it's always a good idea when designing a toggle to not depend solely on an icon, but to reinforce it with other information that clearly indicates the current state.  In this case that's handled by the password field itself, which is either ••••••• or visible text.  In cases where you don't have an obvious visible indication like that it's a good idea to also include at least a label or verb phrase (or hover state, or color/value cue or, well, lots of other tools in the design toolbox) that spells out to the user what's going on.